# How to get cmake to go up one level after setting the Dir

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have this CLion-generated cmake text file for test, using CLion as my editor and Qt as my widget set. I got the idea [here](https://blog.creekorful.org/2019/08/setup-qt-with-clion-easily/).

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I have this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(Qt_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

# Tell cmake where Qt is located
set(Qt6_DIR "/home/fmc/Qt/6.0.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6")

# Tell cmake to find the modules Qt6Core and Qt6widgets
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(Qt_Test main.cpp)
```

My problem is that Qt installed the `Core` and `Widgets` are installed in `/home/fmc/Qt/6.0.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake`

With CMake as it is now, I get these errors:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    /home/fmc/Qt/6.0.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find Qt component "Core" config file at ""

  Failed to find Qt component "Widgets" config file at ""
```

Is there a way to directly set the needed `/home/fmc/Qt/6.0.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake` for the components so as not to interfere with the setting of `/home/fmc/Qt/6.0.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6` ?

Comment: Have you **moved** QT files after **installation**? Otherwise, `Qt6Config.cmake` should correctly find components without additional hints.

Comment: No. I don't move files/folders that's been installed by an installer, which Qt was.

Comment: I set Qt6_FOUND to TRUE in Qt6Config.cmake, but now it can't find other needed files and folders.  I'm not good with cmake, so I don't have a clue abt any of this.

Answer (score 1):

[JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html) had the correct approach to this.  Problem solved.

Comment: Could you be more precise please? Setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` helped?